# How can I re-inflate list fragment after sorting via selection in app bar

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list of items that display just fine in a list fragment. However, I've added a sort button to the app bar and I'm having trouble getting the resorted-data to display (or re-inflate).

This Fragment List Kotlin class successfully calls actionListViewModel.sortActions()

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.new_action -> {
            val action = Action()
            actionListViewModel.addAction(action)
            callbacks?.onActionSelected(action.id)
            true
        }
        R.id.sort_actions -> {
            actionListViewModel.sortActions()
            true

        }
        else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

List View Model function:

```
fun sortActions(){
    actionRepository.getSortedActions()
    Log.d(TAG, "tried to sort")
    // How do I redisplay?

}
```

My Repository Code:

fun getSortedActions(): LiveData<List> = actionDao.getSortedActions()

My Dao Code:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM action ORDER BY title")
fun getSortedActions(): LiveData<List<Action>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

My updated sortActions function:

fun sortActions(){
actionRepository.getSortedActions()

```
    if (sortedItems == true) {
        actionListLiveData = actionRepository.getSortedActions()
        sortedItems = false
    }
    else {
        actionListLiveData = actionRepository.getActions()
        sortedItems = true
    }

}
```

Action Repository code:

```
fun getActions(): LiveData<List<Action>> = actionDao.getActions()
fun getSortedActions(): LiveData<List<Action>> = actionDao.getSortedActions()
```

Which of course, links to the Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM action ORDER BY dueDate")
fun getActions(): LiveData<List<Action>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM action ORDER BY title")
fun getSortedActions(): LiveData<List<Action>>
```

And in my Fragment List, I added:

```
fun reInflate() {
    val fragTransaction: FragmentTransaction = this.fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
        fragTransaction.detach(this)
        fragTransaction.attach(this)
        fragTransaction.commit()
}
```